# AC regime electric circuit problem

Tags: power, ac

I am given the following problem:

When the switch S is closed, current **I=(3-j) A**. Find complex power of current generator **Ig1**, when the switch is opened, if it is known that when switch is opened, complex power of **Ig2** is $$\underline{S_{g2}}^{(o)}=(10+j6) VA.$$
The following data is given:
$$\underline{Z}=(2-j2) \Omega$$
$$\underline{Z_1}=(1+j2) \Omega$$
$$\underline{Z_2}=\underline{Z_4}=(2+j4) \Omega$$
$$\underline{Z_3}=(2-j4) \Omega$$
$$\underline{I_{g1}}=(0.5+j1.5) A$$
$$\underline{E}=(7+j3.5) V$$

Circuit:

[image]

**Attempt:**

When the switch is closed, by using **Potential of nodes method**, we get the system of 3 equations with 4 unknowns, that is not solvable. If we use **Contour currents method**, we get the system of 2 equations with 4 unknowns, that is not solvable. In this case, we have the following unknown data: **E2, E3, Ig2**.

When the switch is opened, we get the same number of unknowns.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot solve that, or better there's a whole subspace of solutions spanning over (E2,E3). I do not fancy too much those solutions methods, they are good to computer aided solvers, but do not "tell" much of what's going on. We humans can do better. Try Nortonize everything on the left of 4-5 instead. Norton impedance can be worked out right away while its current can be easily found toghether with Ig2 on Nortonized circuit using I, Z and Sg2(o) only. Then....

Comment: No no I was wrong! I was partially wrong at least, circuit has actually a subspace of solutions on (E2,E3), but for each point in that subspace power on Ig1 does not change! Can be easily seen splitting E into two. Any idea about that @user300045 ?

Answer (score 2):

Okay as outlined in my comments I'd rather go through a *dividi et impera* approach.

So first point, whatever happens to the switch SW, Z impedance and Ig2 generator the leftside of the circuit can for sure be modelled as per Norton's theorem.

[image]

Norton impedance can be worked out right away 
$$Z_\mathrm{n}=Z_1+Z_3+(Z_2 || Z_4)=4\,\Omega$$
while, for now, we have to leave Norton's current symbolic

---

Then we are told that with SW closed \$I=(3-\mathrm{j})\,\mathrm{A}\$ which in turn just means
$$I_\mathrm{n}+I_\mathrm{g2}=-I=(-3+\mathrm{j})\,\mathrm{A}$$

---

Switching now SW open we need \$V_{54}\$ to calculate \$S_\mathrm{g2}^{(o)}\$
$$V_{54}=(Z_\mathrm{n} || Z)\,(I_\mathrm{n}+I_\mathrm{g2})=-(Z_\mathrm{n} || Z)\,I=(-4+\mathrm{j}4)\,\mathrm{V}$$

---

So now
$$I_\mathrm{g2}^{(o)}=\left(\frac{S_\mathrm{g2}^{(o)}}{V_{54}}\right)^{*}=(-0.5+\mathrm{j}2)\,\mathrm{A}$$
and conversely
$$I_\mathrm{n}=-I+I_\mathrm{g2}=(-2.5-\mathrm{j})\,\mathrm{A}$$

---

We have now completely defined Norton's equivalent of the whole left part of circuit to be \$Z_\mathrm{n}=4\,\Omega\$ and \$I_\mathrm{n}=(-2.5-\mathrm{j})\,\mathrm{A}\$.

It's now time to get back to its original and try to "fill in" its components.

Looking below at the unloaded Norton's equivalent we can measure an open circuit voltage
$$V_\mathrm{n}=Z_\mathrm{n}\,I_\mathrm{n}=(-10-\mathrm{j}4)\,\mathrm{V}$$

---

The same voltage can obviously found at unloaded original circuit as \$V_{54}\$ but, given no current flowing in \$Z_1\$, the same voltage will also be at \$V_{14}\$

[image]

We have now to *reverse* bottom left corner circuit finding \$E_2\$ and \$E_3\$ which will give required \$V_\mathrm{n}\$.

This can be done in several ways, but splitting E voltage generator is probably the simplest.

Thevenin-izing E2,E3,E(left) into one single voltage generator \$E_\mathrm{t}\$ 
 now clarifies that while we do not have enough relations to find \$E_2\$ and \$E_3\$ individual values, there must exist one single \$E_\mathrm{t}\$ achieving required \$V_\mathrm{n}\$.

In short
$$Z_{324}=Z_3+(Z_2\,||\,Z_4)=(3-\mathrm{j}2)\,\Omega$$
$$E_\mathrm{t}=V_\mathrm{n}-Z_{324}\,I_\mathrm{g1}=(5.5+\mathrm{j}2)\,\mathrm{V}$$

---

So now that we have managed to dig out \$I_\mathrm{g1}\$ from Norton's equivalent we can finally fit it all back toghether.

[image]

$$V_{14}=\frac{\frac{E_\mathrm{t}}{Z_{324}}+I_\mathrm{g1}}{\frac{1}{Z_{324}}+\frac{1}{Z_1+Z}}=( 3.675 + \mathrm{j}3.975)\,\mathrm{V}$$

$$V_{13}=V_{14}-E=-3.325 + \mathrm{j}0.475)\,\mathrm{V}$$

and finally

$$S_\mathrm{g1}=V_{13}\,I_\mathrm{g1}^{*}=( -0.95 + \mathrm{j}5.225)\,\mathrm{VA}$$

Comment: I'd like your thoughts too, I would like to guide you to the solution rather than just show how I 've done it

Comment: In your first Norton schema, how did you determined the direction of In? Why is it from 4 to 5? Shouldn't it be from 5 to 4? Could you explain?

Comment: It's a conventional direction, both option are ok as long as you account them in the eqautions you write. Then value of current might be positive or negative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73073/discussion-between-carloc-and-user300045).

Comment: @user300045 please continue the discussion in chat